# Live wallpaper - memory budget exceeded when in preview mode

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, live-wallpaper

I've got this problem with my live wallpaper. It loads about 10 images, one is big enough (960x600) others are much smaller, big one is jpg, smaller in png (becouse of transparency).
Anyway, it works just fine except of the preview mode. When i run it the first time it's fine.
Another time - again ok. But when run third or fourth time - it crashes due to exceeded VM memory budget. 
Seems it loads bitmaps to memory and doesn't delete it after closing preview mode. So how to clean memory after preview mode? So that there'll be space to open it again?

Answer (score 0):

Ok seems I've just found a solution so maybe it'll help anoyone else.
I've added :

```
myBitmap.recycle();
myBitmap1.recycle();
etc...
```

in onDestroy and onSurfaceDestroyed for each of the bitmaps used in my project.
So simple and solved the whole thing.